# Issues with iterating the HashMap in Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am new to Android development, and I need a tip to find a way to solve my problem.

I have a `HashMap`, that includes some frequencies as `keys`, and amplitudes as `values`.

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
hashMap.put(20, 32767);
hashMap.put(32, 32767);
hashMap.put(64, 32767);
hashMap.put(125, 6000);
```

I want the system to iterate this hashmap, and every time it should generate the tone based on the frequency and amplitude, and ask the user if he heard this tone. If yes, then we move to the next entry of the hashmap, if no, then we increment the amplitude and generate the tone again with the incremented amplitude and ask the user again the same question.

I made a for loop that iterates the entries of the hash map, and also used `Iterator` but the problem is that it's showing all the Alerts from the first iteration.

Anyone can help?

**Edit:**

This is the iteration code:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    freqOfTone = entry.getKey();
    amplitude = entry.getValue();
    startCalibration();
}
```

Comment: Show your iteration code. And, I'm not sure you want a hash map for this. You probably want a `Pair` class or something similar.

Comment: Like Keyser plz provide the code

Comment: Iteration looks good.. what is the expected behavior?

Comment: *"but the problem is that it's showing all the Alerts from the first iteration"* This makes no sense. What first iteration? You mean in the first iteration of the posted loop?

Comment: In startCalibration() method, it should generate the tone, and show an alert asking the user if he heard the tone. If yes, then we will continue normally with the next entry, if no then we modify the amplitude and call startCalibration() again. What is happening is that it's showing all the alerts for all the entries in the hashmap once the for loop is executed. If you want, I can provide you with a ll the code.

Comment: @Hanady Do you ever want to look up an amplitude given a specific frequency? Or do you always iterate through the entire thing?

Comment: Your loop will execute `startCalibration()` once for each entry, just like you told it to. If you want to halt execution within the loop, you should add code to the loop.

Comment: Every frequency should have its own amplitude, the amplitude is not the same for all the frequencies.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.

Comment: Presumably you also want to use a TreeMap, not a HashMap, because I'd expect you want to iterate in order by frequency; that's not guaranteed with a HashMap.

Comment: Then you must be doing something different in startCallibration.Can you please post startCallibartion code? What do you mean by alert here? I guess,If you are increasing the amplitude and then moving on to next iterator then in that case, why don't 
you simply sort the hashmap on the basis of amplitude (using a comparator which will take hashmap in it's constructor) and if user is able to hear the lowest amplitude then move on to next, otherwise increase this amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to use something like this?

```
for(int key:hashMap.keySet())
{
    int val = hashMap.get(key)-1;
    do
    {
        val++;
        //Play sound    
    }while(!didYouHereItDialog());
    hashMap.put(key,val);
}
```